# Как отправить get запрос?

Tags: javascript, cors

Почему я не могу получить контент этим скриптом

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      document.body.className = 'ok';
      console.log(request.responseText);
    } else {
      document.body.className = 'error';
    }
  }
};
request.open("GET", "https://opskins.com/ajax/browse_scroll.php?page=1&appId=730&contextId=2", true);
request.send(null);
```

Я отправляю запрос с этой страницы https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_browse. Там я уже авторизовался, но js скрипт все равно не работает.

Comment: добавь `request.withCredentials = true;`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () .. Добавил. В консоли выдает ошибку

Comment: @norbornen Ещё ошибки ). Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'withCredentials' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The value may only be set if the object's state is UNSENT or OPENED.
    at chrome-extension://mipajlnafediioaiklmogkokllfcaamd/content.js:14:25

Comment: так при запросе `https://opskins.com/ajax/browse_scroll.php?page=1&appId=730&contextId=2` действительно 404 статус. как подтвердить, что этот запрос в каких-то обстоятельствах возвращает хороший ответ?

Comment: @norbornen `$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://opskins.com/ajax/browse_scroll.php?page=1&appId=730&contextId=2',
    success: (body) => {
        console.log(body);
    }
});`

Comment: В консоли в браузере ввожу этот код. Тогда я получаю ответ который  мне нужен

Comment: Подсказали что придется инъекцию делать